# Filtering xts objects in Shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny, xts

I'd like to display a basic Shiny dygraph in my Rmarkdown that toggles between networks.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
> head(df)
           nightTrips dayTrips network
2014-05-03          0       16       1
2014-05-04          0        5       1
2014-05-05          0        8       1
2014-05-06          0        3       1
2014-05-07          0        0       1
2014-05-08          0        3       1
> nrow(df)
[1] 2239
```

If I subset the dataframe `df` where `network=1`, I can successfully render a dygraph for a single network with:

```
> head(test)
           nightTrips dayTrips
2014-05-03          0       16
2014-05-04          0        5
2014-05-05          0        8
2014-05-06          0        3
2014-05-07          0        0
2014-05-08          0        3

dygraph(test, main = "Network1") %>%
  dySeries("nightTrips", label = "Night Trips") %>%
  dySeries("dayTrips", label = "dayTrips") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

But when I bind my data into one dataframe, add an extra column `netowrk` that specifies network, convert it to an xts object, and try to start a Shiny server - I get an error that a filter cannot be applied to xts object:

[image]

Is there a known workaround for this issue? 
Here is the code for the inline Shiny app:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Sample Timeseries"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("networknames")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("networksgraph"))
  )
),

  server = function(input, output) {

    data <- df
    data <- as_xts(data, date_col = day)


    output$networksgraph <- renderDygraph({
      if (is.null(input$networkname)) return (NULL)
        filtered <- filter(data,
                           network == intput$networkname) %>%
        dygraph()

    })

    output$networknames <- renderUI({
    selectInput("networkname", "Select your Network",
                choices = c(1,2,3))
  })
}
)

```
````

Comment: Why convert the entire data frame to xts?  It seems that `data$network` should continue being numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of applying `dplyr` functions to `xts` objects was identified but maybe has not been solved. If your `dygraph()` function has nothing to do with the time index, then you can simply use the `coredata()` as in `filtered <- filter(coredata(data), network == intput$networkname)`. In the other case, you have to convert back and forth between `xts` and `data.frame`.